How to use toolchains with Bzlmod?
I am using Bazel version 7.1.1. I have some trouble using toolchains with Bzlmod. Here is how my demo looks like. There is a folder named rules_foo. This folder contains an empty WORKSPACE.bazel file. This seems to be needed since otherwise rules_foo cannot be referenced as a module. Then three is a foo.bzl file with the following content:
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

def _foo_library_impl(ctx):
    ctx.actions.write(ctx.outputs.out, content = "#define PI 3.14")

    return [DefaultInfo(
        files = depset([ctx.outputs.out]),
    )]

foo_library = rule(
    implementation = _foo_library_impl,

    attrs = {
        "out": attr.output(
            doc = """
            Name of the generated header file.
            """,
            mandatory = True,
        ),
    },

    doc = "Generates a header file",
)

def foo_cc_library(name, **kwargs):
    foo_library(
        name = "{0}_foo_library_generated".format(name),
        out = "{0}.h".format(name)
    )

    cc_library(
        name = name,
        hdrs = [name + ".h"],
        **kwargs
    )

The idea of foo_cc_library is to generate a header file that can be added as a cc_library dependency to some cc_library or cc_binary target. Currently, this foo_library just creates a header file that contains #define PI 3.14.
The MODULE.bazel file looks like this:
module(
    name = "rules_foo",
    version = "0.0.1",
)

bazel_dep(name = "rules_cc", version = "0.0.9")

Then there is a tests folder within the rules_foo folder named tests. The folder rules_foo contains also a .bazelignore file that ignores that test folder. The test folder itself has also a MODULE.bazel file and references the parent directory since it wants to make use of rules_foo:
bazel_dep(name = "rules_foo")
local_path_override(
    module_name = "rules_foo",
    path = "..",
)

Then there is a BUILD.bazel file within the tests folder:
load("@rules_foo//:foo.bzl", "foo_cc_library")
cc_binary(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    deps = [":foolib"],
)

foo_cc_library(
    name = "foolib",
)

The main.cpp looks like this:
#include <iostream>

#include "foolib.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "PI: " << PI << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

If I run this program I get the expected output:
PI: 3.14

Instead of hardcoding the generated code into a Skylark rule I want to generate the header by an external tool. As a first step, I came up with a simple C++ header generator that looks like this (demo_compiler.cpp):
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename> <value>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string filename = argv[1];
    double value = std::stod(argv[2]);

    std::ofstream headerFile(filename);
    if (!headerFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to create file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    headerFile << "#ifndef CONSTANTS_H\n";
    headerFile << "#define CONSTANTS_H\n\n";
    headerFile << "#define PI " << value << "\n\n";
    headerFile << "#endif // CONSTANTS_H\n";

    headerFile.close();

    std::cout << "Header file '" << filename << "' generated successfully.\n";

    return 0;
}

Three is a BUILD file in the rules_foo folder. It contains this content
cc_binary(
    name = "demo_compiler",
    srcs = ["demo_compiler.cpp"],
)

My idea was to use the toolchain feature of Bazel to get this working (just for the record: later on the demo_compiler will be replaced by a real LLVM-based prebuild compiler that also generates an object file).
I wonder how I can introduce a toolchain. My attempt was this way:
Create a toolchain.bzl file within the rules_foo folder:
FOO_TOOLCHAIN = "@rules_foo//:foo_toolchain_type"

def _foo_toolchain_info(ctx):
    return [
        platform_common.ToolchainInfo(
            compiler = ctx.attr.compiler,
            flags = ctx.attr.flags,
        ),
    ]

foo_toolchain_info = rule(
    _foo_toolchain_info,
    attrs = {
        "_compiler": attr.label(
            executable = True,
            default = "//:demo_compiler",
            cfg = "host",
        ),
        "flags": attr.string_list(),
    },
)

Add to the BUILD.bazel file in the rules_foo folder the following lines:
load("@rules_foo//:toolchain.bzl", "FOO_TOOLCHAIN", "foo_toolchain_info")

foo_toolchain_info(
    name = "two_decimals",
    flags = ["3.14"],
)

#foo_toolchain_info(
#    name = "three_decimals",
#    flags = ["3.141"],
#)

toolchain(
    name = "foo_toolchain_linux_x86_64",
    exec_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
    ],
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain = ":two_decimals",
    toolchain_type = FOO_TOOLCHAIN,
)

And add to the MODULE.bazel file the following code:
register_toolchains(
    "//:foo_toolchain_linux_x86_64",
)

If I try to do a bazel build //... within the rules_foo folder I just get an error:
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:demo_compiler' failed; build aborted

I wonder also if adding the toolchain to the MODULE.bazel file of rules_foo is the right way. Maybe no toolchain should be added here and instead of this a module extension should be introduced here. I do not exactly know how to proceed here further. Would be happy if someone could show me how demo_compiler could be packed in a toolchain and used in the tests folder.
